# MATLAB to Python Code Conversion - Image.open issue

Tags: python, matlab

[image]Okay so I'm manually converting MATLAB to Python and I'm not able to convert certain snippets because I'm not that great at Python

I have this black and white image that I took out from a piece of MATLAB code. In MATLAB its dimensions are (according to the `size` function): `1944 2592`

I save this image as a .jpg and open in Python using the following code:

```
img = Image.open("csm1.jpg")
img = np.array(img)
print img
```

I get the output as:

```
[[[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 ..., 
 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  ..., 
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]]
[[  0   0   0]
 [  0   0   1]
 [  0   0   2]
 ..., 
 [571 812   0]
 [571 812   1]
 [571 812   2]]
```

I don't understand how a black and white photo which is 2D in MATLAB became a completely white image 3D in Python. I've attached the photo too. Can anyone help in this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the MATLAB code used to save this as well as the output of `img.shape`?

Comment: @Suever I used `figure, imshow' and then saved it as a .jpg from the MATLAB window. `img.shape` gives me a output: `(572, 813, 3)` in Python

Comment: You  should use `imwrite` to write the image data to a file directly. Saving from the figure will save a lot of whitespace around the image

Comment: In fact you can even see the white around the image when you view it outside of stack overflow's white background. Thus you should expect that the loaded image should have a lot of white in the first set of values.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly @Suever. I'll modify this question now to the next issue I have that follows the code

Comment: @NikhilHegde Please ask a *new* question as your edit differed significantly from your original question. I have rolled back your changes

Comment: Okay no problem. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save your image data as MATLAB sees it, you will want to save it using [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html?refresh=true) rather than first displaying it using `imshow` and saving the figure.

```
imwrite(img, 'filename.jpg')
```

The difference is that the "save as" method saves an image *as you see it on the screen* which includes a white bounding box. Also, the actual dimensions of the data are not taken into account when determining the dimensions of the output image, only the size of the figure.

Also, even if your image is grayscale in MATLAB (2D), when you save this to a JPEG using `imwrite` it will be converted to an RGB image (3D) when saved.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind! Do not use MATLAB figure window to save an image, instead use `imwrite`. Got it! Thanks!